# How can I initiate a new function, immediately after a function is successful in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to run a function, just after a function is completed, and also pass some data into the second function.
I have tested the two functions individually, they both work. But I want to initiate the second one immediately after the first is complete

This is my code below but the second function didn't run properly.

```
const ChargeCard = (dispatch) => ({
    cardNumber,
    expiryMonth,
    expiryYear,
    cvc,
    email,
    amountInKobo,
    id
}) => {

    try {
        RNPaystack.chargeCard({
            cardNumber: cardNumber,
            expiryMonth: expiryMonth,
            expiryYear: expiryYear,
            cvc: cvc,
            email: email,
            amountInKobo: amountInKobo * 100

        })
            .then(response => {

                if (response) {
                    setBasic({ id }) //the function to run if this is successful
                }                
            })

    } catch {

        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_ERROR",
            payload:
                "Something went wrong during payment, please try again, don't worry you have not been charged."
        });    
    }

};
```

This function I want to run immediately that is successful;

```
const setBasic = () => async ({ id }) => {
    const Basic = 1
    const response = await appApi.put(`/usersub/${id}`, { Basic });
    if (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what "not working" means?

Comment: Re edit: Can you be **much** more explicit on what "didn't run properly" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second function to this:

```
const setBasic = async ({ id }) => {
    const Basic = 1
    const response = await appApi.put(`/usersub/${id}`, { Basic });
    if (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }
}
```

You've defined it as:

```
const setBasic = () => async ({ id }) => {
```

but you are calling it with:

```
 setBasic({ id })
```

Comment: The first function `ChargeCard` is not async.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It's the return value of `RNPaystack.chargeCard()` which has the `then()` method called on it.

Comment: I see, yes. The second function is a fn that returns a fn, but they are only invoking the outer fn.

Comment: Which, in turn, invokes `setBasic` (assuming the `if` condition passes).

Answer (score 1):

why mix `async await` with `then()` stick with one and be consistent with it.

```
const setBasic = async ({ id }) => {
    const Basic = 1
    const response = await appApi.put(`/usersub/${id}`, { Basic });
    if (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }
}

const ChargeCard = (dispatch) => async ({
    cardNumber,
    expiryMonth,
    expiryYear,
    cvc,
    email,
    amountInKobo,
    id
}) => {

    try {
        const response = await RNPaystack.chargeCard({
            cardNumber: cardNumber,
            expiryMonth: expiryMonth,
            expiryYear: expiryYear,
            cvc: cvc,
            email: email,
            amountInKobo: amountInKobo * 100

        })
        if(response) setBasic({ id }) //the function to run if this is successful

    } catch {

        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_ERROR",
            payload:
                "Something went wrong during payment, please try again, don't worry you have not been charged."
        });    
    }

};
```

This way your login is consistent. However, I just want to mention this; your first function looks like a shorthand way to write `action creators using redux-thunk` in case I am right, I think you are passing the `dispatch` wrongly in the first function. You should rewrite your function to this:

```
const ChargeCard = ({
    cardNumber,
    expiryMonth,
    expiryYear,
    cvc,
    email,
    amountInKobo,
    id
}) => async dispatch => {

    try {
        const response = await RNPaystack.chargeCard({
            cardNumber: cardNumber,
            expiryMonth: expiryMonth,
            expiryYear: expiryYear,
            cvc: cvc,
            email: email,
            amountInKobo: amountInKobo * 100

        })
        if(response) setBasic({ id }) //the function to run if this is successful

    } catch {

        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_ERROR",
            payload:
                "Something went wrong during payment, please try again, don't worry you have not been charged."
        });    
    }

};
```